# Umbraco: Determining Who Last Updated Content

Tags: umbraco

I see in the API there is a way to grab the UpdateDate field.  Is there a way to determine WHO made the last update to a particular content node?  In other words, the user ID of the person that last edited a particular node?

Here's some of the code I'm attempting to use:

```
Document[] releaseDocs = Document.GetRootDocuments();
User currentUser = User.GetCurrent();

foreach (var doc in releaseDocs)
{ 
   docPermissions = currentUser.GetPermissions(doc.Path);
   if ((docPermissions.Contains("F")) && (docPermissions.Contains("U")))
   {
      if (doc.HasPendingChanges())
      {
         if (doc.ParentId > -1)
         {
              lblPageContent += doc.Writer.Name;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research on this and, while writerID and writerName are supposed to store the last editor, there appears to be a bug in Umbraco.  Their support suggested creating a hidden field that updates with the editor user data, so that's my temporary work around for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `writerName` and `writerID` same way you use `UpdateDate` like as below:

if you are using Razor you can use as below:

```
@Model.writerName
@Model.writerID
```

in XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$currentpage/@writerName" />
<xsl:value-of select="$currentpage/@writerID" />
```

in C# Usercontrol:

```
using System;
using umbraco.NodeFactory;

namespace UmbracoTestingProj
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Node node = Node.GetCurrent();
            int writerId = node.WriterID;
            string wrtierName = node.WriterName;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this would help,

if you have question just just comment below

Comment: It looks like the Model.Writer.Name has the same problem that Model.User.Name has - it's the name of the person who created the document, not the name of the person who last edited it.  Is there a way to get this information from this or another variable?

Comment: what version of umbraco are you using because after umbraco 4.5 it has new schema it is the last updated person is `writerID` or `writerName`, it has also attribute called `creatorId` and `creatorName`, just check this link out: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/45-xml-schema

Comment: I'm not using XSLT, I'm trying to write user control in ASP.NET, so I don't know if that has any impact.  I'm using the latest build -  4.8.0.

Comment: then it would be `Node node = new Node(1234);` and then `node.writerId` or `node.writerName` i am hopping that would be the case. I haven't tried it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I tried a few different permutations of it but I'm still always getting the document creator.

Comment: Okk, I got the root I think, can you try removing you reference Umbraco and now select new dll from your new version which is umbraco 4.8 and bin folder and try adding reference now,it should work, because it could be the case that you might have old dll.

Comment: OK, I switched out the DLL.  You were right, I was pointing to an older version (stupid mistake).  I posted some code above to show kinda what I'm trying to do.  I also tried adding a Node node = new Node(doc.Id) and tried grabbing node.WriterName but EVERY time it gives me the document creator, not the last editor.  I confirmed the last editor is different too.  Ugh, I feel like it's so close but I'm missing something.  Thank you SO much for your help!

Comment: I checked the cmsPreviewXml table in Umbraco and the writerName is set to the Admin that created the document, not the user that updated it.  This is probably where the problem lies - why isn't Umbraco updating this properly, is this a bug in the system?